# SPARQL QUERY in Protege 4.3

Tags: regex, ontology, protege, swrl

I have three class in my ontology

```
class babyAge (6+, 8+, 12+)
class taste (asam, manis, asin)
class food (recipe name)
```

i want to querying data food for babyAge (6+) and have taste (asam)

i use this code in my java program (i dont know if there are other code more simple than this one, if you know please tell me too) :

```
SELECT ?babyAge ?taste ?food  
WHERE { ?babyAge mpasi:hasResep ?food.
?food mpasi:hasRasa ?taste.
FILTER regex(str(?babyAge),"6+").
FILTER regex (str(?taste),"asam")}
```

and i get my data. but when i execute that code in protege, i dont get anything. Can someone help me?

Comment: If FILTER expects a regex, and the string you search for is `6+`, your regex should be `"6[+]"`

Comment: it still doesn't work in protege...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without seeing the ontology.

My first move would be to ensure `mpasi` is bound to the same value in the ontology and in your query - it might be a case of mismatched IRIs.

You might also want to try without filters and see if anything is returned.